# Tight VNC Server, Ubutu 12.10 and unity desktop

Tags: unity, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvncserver

I've done the following but all I get in VNC Viewer is a blank orange screen, any help appreciated.

1. `apt-get -y install ubuntu-desktop tightvncserver`
2. `adduser vnc && passwd vnc`
3. `echo "vnc ALL=(ALL)       ALL" >> /etc/sudoers`
4. `sudo -u vnc vncpasswd`
5. `nano ~/.vnc/xstartup` and enter the following:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
   unset SESSION_MANAGER
   . /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

   [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
   [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
   xsetroot -solid grey
   vncconfig -iconic &
   x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1280x1024+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
   #x-window-manager &
   ```

   save
6. `sudo nano /etc/init.d/vncserver`, paste in the following, then save:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh -e
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          vncserver
   # Required-Start:    networking
   # Default-Start:     3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 6
   ### END INIT INFO

   PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/"

   # The Username:Group that will run VNC
   export USER="vnc"
   #${RUNAS}

   # The display that VNC will use
   DISPLAY="1"

   # Color depth (between 8 and 32)
   DEPTH="16"

   # The Desktop geometry to use.
   #GEOMETRY="<WIDTH>x<HEIGHT>"
   #GEOMETRY="800x600"
   GEOMETRY="1024x768"
   #GEOMETRY="1280x1024"

   # The name that the VNC Desktop will have.
   NAME="my-vnc-server"

   OPTIONS="-name ${NAME} -depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY}"

   . /lib/lsb/init-functions

   case "$1" in
   start)
   log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on   localhost:${DISPLAY}"
   su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}"
   ;;

   stop)
   log_action_begin_msg "Stopping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}"
   su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}"
   ;;

   restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
   esac

   exit 0
   ```

   Then ctrl-x to save, Y for Yes, and enter to accept file name.
7. `chown -R vnc. /home/vnc/.vnc && chmod +x /home/vnc/.vnc/xstartup`
8. `sed -i 's/allowed_users.*/allowed_users=anybody/g' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`
9. `chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver && service vncserver start`
10. `update-rc.d vncserver defaults`
11. reboot.
12. *finally,* go in there with tightvnc viewer client, and voila, blank kool aid tangerine orange screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't set gui session for xstartup file, that is why you see blank screen when try try to remotely connect to your desktop/server via vnc on ubuntu, if you want gnome, install these packages

```
# apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

and use this xstartup file

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Comment: Thanks Biana, at the end back in Feb 2014 I ended up finding instructions for something that gave me gnome core, so I gave in and went with that.. next time out I will try yours. Many thanks.

Comment: all set now for some reason i had some settings on mine that were hiding my window title bars. your xstartup here works fine

Answer (score -2):

From what i've seen you cant vnc into unity.  Install a different desktop environment and you'll be good.  Heres how woth xfce:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-vnc-for-ubuntu-12

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Quoting: `From what i've seen you cant vnc into unity`. Can you reference to link stating that users cannot vnc into unity?